# Python Flask: Unable to access flask app using public ip

Tags: python, flask

Here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello world!"

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="33")
```

I can access it using 192.168.0.4:33 on my phone and 127.0.0.1:33 on the pc it is running on, but cannot access it using my public ip. Seeing 2 similar questions on stackoverflow(which did not resolve my issue), I also tried changing the host to 192.168.0.4 and turning off the firewall, but I simply can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:**
Copy pasting a comment of mine on this question,

It appears to be a router issue and not port specific. I never configured the router for remote management, which probably is the issue here, and I've had no luck finding the manual online for the router config interface. I guess I'll test stuff from within the local network until greater need arises.

**Edit:**
Set up port forwarding, but it still doesn't work. Also changed the port in the code to 5010. [image]

Comment: Try the same code but change the port number to 8000(basically anything above 2000), and check if it works.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :/

Comment: Have you configured your router to pass port 33 through, and have you confirmed that it actually works?

Comment: It turned out to be a router issue and not port specific. I never configured the router for remote management, which probably is the issue here, and I've had no luck finding the manual online for the router config interface. I guess I'll test stuff from within the local network until greater need arises.

Comment: @Cracin remote management means that public IPs can change router config. You just need port forwarding set up correctly.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the info. I'm not all that familiar with networking. I guess I got confused between em. Thank you, I'll look into it.

Comment: Sometimes running the run command in the terminal does the job :

flask run --host=0.0.0.0

Comment: @Jean-Michel Provencher Not working in my case :/

Answer (score 1):

Ports up to 1024 are [restricted to the root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only).
So, as @TheCreator232 pointed out, you may want to go above 1024.

In addition, check the [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) ([tutorial](https://learntomato.com/what-is-port-forwarding-how-to-open-ports-on-a-router/)) of your router for the port you decide on.

There are online tools to check whether a port is open: [yougetsignal.com](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), [canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org/).

Comment: Tried a few ports ranging for 33 to 8000, seems to work on none. I used port 33 after some posts said it worked for them on that port.

Comment: Port 33 is at least not associated with any [system process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports). But you may need root access rights to use it.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the info. I'll keep testing stuff on other ports.

Comment: I just set up port forwarding, still doesn't seem to work. Updated the question with a screenshot of it.